# Forcing a Linux Sort to Treat a Record With Spaces as a Single Data Column

Tags: linux, sorting

Here is a fixed-length set of records that I want to sort with Linux by the zip-code field that starts at offset 20.

```
Boise               83701
Las Vegas           88901
East St. Louis      62071
```

(In reality I am dealing with a much larger dataset with hundreds of fields and gigabytes of data, so reformatting is not an option.  This is an example stripped down to the essentials of the problem).

This doesn't work:

```
sort -k2.1 -k2.5
```

...because the variable number of spaces in the city-names gives the appearance of a different number of columns in each record.
 
 
 
Here is a hack that does work:

```
sort -t\t -k1.20 -k1.24
```

...but it assumes no stray tabs in any of the records.
 
 
 
My question is, is there a direct way to force a Linux sort to not treat spaces as a delimiter and treat each line as a single data-column, that does not depend on the absence of a particular character throughout the data?

Comment: How should a tab be handled? Would it not be much better to normalize whitespace as part of the process?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that doesn't require 100s of gigabytes of data to be reformatted, to do a simple sort on a fixed position set of fields.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the start character position (and end position if needed) should do it.

With start position:

```
$ sort -k1.21 file
East St. Louis      62071
Boise               83701
Las Vegas           88901
```

Or start and end position:

```
$ sort -k1.21,1.25 file
East St. Louis      62071
Boise               83701
Las Vegas           88901
```

Add the `--debug` option to visualize the character positions.

Comment: Doesn't this result in a sort on "East", "Boise" and "Las"?

Comment: It looks like that because the cities have the same order as the zip codes. Rename the cities to `c`, `a`, `b` and compare.